# Intersect Array of object in iOS swift with efficiency and without using for loop

Tags: swift

I want to Intersect two arrays that contains "People" objects and array size could be more then 10000 for each array and i want to intersect using "id" of objects without using for loop. i have already used for loop my solution but speed is slow. Some People objects can have same "id" in both array and some objects can have different "id"'s.

Below is sample example of my code

Example :

```
class People {

    var id:Int!

    var name:String!

}

let object1 = People(10, John)

let object2 = People(5, Rocky)

let array1 = [object1, object2, .... , object10000]

let array2 = [objectA1, objectA2, .... , objectA10000]
```

Comment: "Intersect". What's the condition of equality?

Comment: @Larme `id`. It's there in the question.

Comment: Have you tried using `NSSet/Set`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set

Comment: What do you mean by intersect? Intersection usually means something common between two things. Here, you seem to be talking about filtering but using the word _intersection_.

Comment: I want to take out objects those are not present in array1. I tried with NSSet/Set. but not getting solution for me

Comment: But you say you want to compare only with id, if you want the objects that are in both array1 and array2, then it is not just a match of `id`, but both `id` and `name`.

Comment: @harishchandragangavane Can you check my answer

Comment: You said, "I want to take out objects those are not present in array1." You can't take objects out of `array1` because it's a let. Can you show us the slow code you already wrote so we can see what you want in the result? Also, is order important?

Answer (score 4):

You can create Set with PeopleIds and Set with Object Id, something like this:

```
let peoples = ...
let objects = ...

let peoplesIds = peoples.map { $0.id }
let objectsIds = objects.map { $0.id }

let peoplesIdsSet = Set(peoplesIds)
let objectsIdsSet= Set(objectsIds)

let intersectionsIds = Array(peoplesIdsSet.intersection(objectsIdsSet))
```

Also I advise you to put it work in background thread, something like this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    findIntersecionsIds()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // done
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example

Suppose your struct is

```
struct User:Hashable {
    let id:Int
}
```

and your array

```
let array1 = [User(id:1),User(id:2),User(id:3),User(id:4),User(id:5)]
let array2 = [User(id:1),User(id:20),User(id:3),User(id:4),User(id:5)]
```

Now you can create set

```
let set1:Set<Int> = Set(array1.map{$0.id})
let set2:Set<Int> = Set(array2.map{$0.id})
```

and

```
let unique = set1.intersection(set2)
let elements = (array1 + array2).filter{unique.contains($0.id)}
print(elements)
```

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 1):

The best way to perform an intersection is to use a `Set`.  In order to add your items to a set, they need to be `Hashable`.  Here is an implementation of your `People` class that is `Hashable`, and `CustomStringConvertible` (so that is can be printed nicely):

```
class People: Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {

    var id: Int
    var name: String

    var hashValue: Int { return id }
    var description: String { return "People(name: \(name), id: \(id)" }


    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }

    // In order to conform to Hashable, you also need to be Equatable
    // Here we define equality as having the same id        
    static func ==(lhs: People, rhs: People) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

let object1 = People(id: 10, name: "John")
let object2 = People(id: 5, name: "Rocky")

let array1 = [object1, object2]

let array2 = [People(id: 10, name: "John"), People(id: 7, name: "Jane")]

let intersection = Array(Set(array1).intersection(array2))
print(intersection)
```

> ```
> [People(name: John, id: 10]
> ```

Comment: I am sorry if i am wrong but he needs only in ID field. He don't want any other parameter to match !!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an `Array` of `People`, which is made from `array2` by *take out objects those are not present in array1*.

Then just 2 lines:

```
let idSet1 = Set(array1.lazy.map{$0.id})
let interSection = array2.filter{idSet1.contains($0.id)}
```

Testing code:

```
import Foundation

class People {
    var id: Int
    var name: String

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

do {
    //Generate random testing data
    let array1: [People] = (0..<20000).filter{_ in Int.random(in: 0...1) == 0}.map{People(id: $0, name: "P($0)")}
    print(array1.count)
    let array2: [People] = (0..<20000).filter{_ in Int.random(in: 0...1) == 0}.map{People(id: $0, name: "P($0)")}
    print(array2.count)

    let start = Date()
    let idSet1 = Set(array1.lazy.map{$0.id})
    let interSection = array2.filter{idSet1.contains($0.id)}
    let end = Date()
    print(interSection.count, end.timeIntervalSince(start))
}
```